# Scheduled task creation in Ansible with option to keep it running forever

Tags: windows, ansible, ansible-2.x

I have created a playbook to create a scheduled task in windows. See below:

```
- name: Create Task
  win_scheduled_task:
    name: "{{ memcache_task_name }}"
    description: Startup for Memcache service
    state: present
    triggers:
      - type: boot
    enabled: yes
    logon_type: password
    run_level: highest
    actions:
      - path: "{{ memcache_dir }}"
    author: "author"
    username: "user"
    password: "password"
    restart_count: 3
    restart_interval: "PT5M"
```

However, the task that gets created has the option "Stop the task if it runs longer than: 3 days" selected.

I don't want this task to stop. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried the `execution_time_limit` that was added in 2.5 to the [win_scheduled_task](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/modules/win_scheduled_task_module.html) module.

Comment: I have not set its value with the sole purpose of setting it to infinite, as the documentation states. However, it is still set to 3 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution thanks to the comment from @Welsh

Just needed to add

> execution_time_limit: PT0S